# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, fxml

Tengo un problema, que es el siguiente. Me muestra este error

**Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableView.setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)" because "this.tblAutomovil" is null**

Y esto me pasa cuando pongo en el codigo esto:

**tblAutomovil.setItems(automoviles);**

Anexo el codigo de mi clase:

```
private TableView <Automovil> tblAutomovil;
ObservableList <Automovil> automoviles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    initAutomoviles();
    tblAutomovil.setItems(automoviles);
}
```

> ```
> private void initAutomoviles(){
>
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Audi", "A3", "Azul", 860, "Automatica", "A3.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("BMW", "A3", "Azul", 560, "Automatica", "BMW.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Nissan", "Tsuru", "Blanco", 500, "Manual", "Tsuru.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Toyota", "Tacoma", "Roja", 1200, "Automatica", "Tacoma.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Honda", "Civic", "Blanco", 710, "Automatica", "Civic.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Ford", "Fusion", "Blanco", 800, "Automatica", "Fusion.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Amarillo", 900, "Manual", "Camaro.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Audi", "R8", "Blanco", 910, "Automatica", "R8.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("BMW", "A3", "Azul", 560, "Automatica", "BMW.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Nissan", "Tsuru", "Blanco", 500, "Manual", "Tsuru.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Toyota", "Tacoma", "Roja", 1200, "Automatica", "Tacoma.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Honda", "Civic", "Blanco", 710, "Automatica", "Civic.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Ford", "Fusion", "Blanco", 800, "Automatica", "Fusion.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Amarillo", 900, "Manual", "Camaro.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Audi", "TT", "Naranja", 790, "Automatica", "TT.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("BMW", "A3", "Azul", 560, "Automatica", "BMW.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Nissan", "Tsuru", "Blanco", 500, "Manual", "Tsuru.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Toyota", "Tacoma", "Roja", 1200, "Automatica", "Tacoma.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Honda", "Civic", "Blanco", 710, "Automatica", "Civic.jpg"));
>     automoviles.add(new Automovil("Ford", "Fusion", "Blanco", 800, "Automatica", "Fusion.jpg"));
> }
> ```

Comment: No estás instanciando el `TableView` en ningún momento. Prueba a hacer algo como esto: `private final TableView<Automovil> tblAutomovil = new TableView<>();` Para más detalles revisa el código de [este tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0650__JavaFX_TableView.htm), en especial el apartado titulado ***Add New Rows***

Comment: Muchismas gracias, ya no me da error pero sigue sin aparececerme los datos :c

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre ahora, aparece el `TableView` vacío? Pulsa en [edit] y muestra cómo tienes el código ahora. Depura también que `initialize()` se esté ejecutando.

Answer (score 1):

Puedo ver que llamas `initAutomoviles()` para inicializar pero en realiza inicializas una variable dentro de una clase,por lo que `tblAutomovil` no esta dejando de tener valor null.

```
initAutomoviles();
tblAutomovil.setItems(automoviles);
```

Te sugiero cambies tu mètodo que retorne una lista de objetos `Automovil`:

```
//private void initAutomoviles(){
private List<Automovil> initAutomoviles(){

    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Audi", "A3", "Azul", 860, "Automatica", "A3.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("BMW", "A3", "Azul", 560, "Automatica", "BMW.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Nissan", "Tsuru", "Blanco", 500, "Manual", "Tsuru.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Toyota", "Tacoma", "Roja", 1200, "Automatica", "Tacoma.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Honda", "Civic", "Blanco", 710, "Automatica", "Civic.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Ford", "Fusion", "Blanco", 800, "Automatica", "Fusion.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Amarillo", 900, "Manual", "Camaro.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Audi", "R8", "Blanco", 910, "Automatica", "R8.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("BMW", "A3", "Azul", 560, "Automatica", "BMW.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Nissan", "Tsuru", "Blanco", 500, "Manual", "Tsuru.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Toyota", "Tacoma", "Roja", 1200, "Automatica", "Tacoma.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Honda", "Civic", "Blanco", 710, "Automatica", "Civic.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Ford", "Fusion", "Blanco", 800, "Automatica", "Fusion.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Amarillo", 900, "Manual", "Camaro.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Audi", "TT", "Naranja", 790, "Automatica", "TT.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("BMW", "A3", "Azul", 560, "Automatica", "BMW.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Nissan", "Tsuru", "Blanco", 500, "Manual", "Tsuru.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Toyota", "Tacoma", "Roja", 1200, "Automatica", "Tacoma.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Honda", "Civic", "Blanco", 710, "Automatica", "Civic.jpg"));
    automoviles.add(new Automovil("Ford", "Fusion", "Blanco", 800, "Automatica", "Fusion.jpg"));
}
```

de esta forma simplemente llama el mètodo:

```
//initAutomoviles();
tblAutomovil.setItems(initAutomoviles());
```

Comment: No funciona, pongo el return automoviles y me dice que tengo que hacer un casteo en la variable tblAutomovil.setItems(initAutomoviles()); lo cual hago de la siguiente manera tblAutomovil.setItems((ObservableList<Automovil>) initAutomoviles()); y me sigue dando el mismo error: "javafx.scene.control.TableView.setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)" because "this.tblAutomovil" is null